# [Error: Can't find npm module 'react/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]

Tags: json, meteor, reactjs

Please I need to understand what I must do to take care of this problem

"[Error: Can't find npm module 'react/package.json'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?]" I kept having as I try to develop app in meteor with react.

I really do not know what triggers the error.

Thanks for your anticipated assistance.

Comment: I think You You miss one of package.
Please try run `meteor npm install --save react react-dom react-addons-transition-group
react-addons-css-transition-group react-addons-linked-state-mixin react-addons-create-fragment react-addons-update react-addons-pure-render-mixin react-addons-test-utils react-addons-perf`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install react and react-addons-pure-render-mixin.

```
npm install --save react react-addons-pure-render-mixin
```

I was having the same issue from react-meteor-data package when I tried to start my app.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data